# custom view not align centre

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

i am drawing canavasarc but some how it always start from left  i am it should start from middle

```
  float x = 0.25f;
    final float radius = x * (new Float(dpi));
    mRadius = Math.round(radius) + 20;

 mRect = new RectF(
            getWidth() + mStrokeWidth, getWidth() + mStrokeWidth, getWidth() + (mRadius / 2) - mStrokeWidth, getWidth() + (mRadius / 2) - mStrokeWidth
    );
        canvas.drawArc(mRect, lastDegree, mSectionDegree, false, mPaint);
```

why this view always starts from left even i have given gravity centre still

```
float Degree = 270 + (mGap / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < mTotalSections; i++) {

        fillColor(i);
        canvas.drawArc(mRect, Degree, mDegree, false, mPaint);
        Degree += mDegree + mGap;
        Paint mPaint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint1.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint1.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint1.setTextSize(15 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mPaint1.setColor(getResources().getColor(black));

        mPaint1.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        canvas.drawText(text, mRect.centerX(), mRect.centerY(), mPaint1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do but your rect looks weird. A rect more like that should would be better:

```
 mRect = new RectF(
        0 + mStrokeWidth, 0 + mStrokeWidth, getWidth() - mStrokeWidth, getHeight - mStrokeWidth
);
```

But a little draw about what you want and the values of your angle would be perfect ;). I will edit my answer if you provide it.

Edit:
So if you want a circle in the middle of your custom view you can do something like that:

```
 RectF mRect = new RectF(
            50 + mStrokeWidth, 50 + mStrokeWidth, getWidth() -50 - mStrokeWidth, getHeight() -50 - mStrokeWidth
    );

    canvas.drawArc(mRect, 0,360,false,paint);
```

result(the blue lines are the limit of my view):
[image: circle]

You have to modify the 50 to fit what you want ;).
If you want an arc that stick to the edges with an angle of 180 degrees:

```
RectF mRect = new RectF(
             mStrokeWidth,  mStrokeWidth, getWidth()  - mStrokeWidth, getHeight()  - mStrokeWidth
    );

    canvas.drawArc(mRect, 0,180,false,paint);
```

Result:

[image: Arc]

Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: so problem is my circle is always at left side i want it should come to centre

Comment: with this view is not visible ..check qus i have edited

Comment: Would be perfect if you could show me a draw of what you want.